# DoCmd.SetOrderBy method MS Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a problem with the **DoCmd.SetOrderBy** method applied by my report.

1. I have a table with the name **"Types_Docuements"** and columns:

   - ID
   - Document_Name
   - Version
2. Then I have a Report based on this table.
3. I want to order the data based on ID or Document_Name.
4. The **report property sheet** has this setting:

   - Record Source - Types_Documents
   - Filter - empty
   - Filter on Load - Yes (I tried also no)
   - Order by - id
   - Order by on load - yes
   - Allow Filters - yes

**My VBA code is:**

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmd_id_desc_Click()

DoCmd.SetOrderBy ("id DESC")

End Sub
```

However, I am not able to do that neither in Property Sheet manually nor with VBA. I guess that VBA code works, because after its trigger the property sheets changes. But order of the data is still the same.

Thank you for your advice,

Vaclav

Comment: I replicated the table and the report with a button to sort the form and it all worked.  I could not replicate the problem

Comment: However, I assumed that the table name was Types_Documents not Types_Docuements

Comment: Mazoula, thank you for the help. Yes, your are right, it works when I tried it on completely new report. My previous report is probably defect.

Comment: Glad to help; same thing has happened to me several times :)